# Incorrect Number of Bindings applied: needs 4, applied 0 in SQLite3?

Tags: python, database, tkinter, sqlite

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been through everything I could find on the internet and I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. I have four user-entered variables fname, lname, uname and password. I'm passing these to a function that fills them to a database, except, it doesn't.

I have checked for sure that these variables are not empty. I have tried putting them in tuples, experimented with commas but nothing seems to help. Here is the line that has the error:

```
cur.execute("insert into Sample values (?, ?, ?, ?)"), ([fname, lname, uname, password])
```

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 4, and there are 0 supplied.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so apparently this was a syntax error. The parentheses should end after the parameters as:

```
cur.execute("insert into Sample values (?, ?, ?, ?)", (fname, lname, uname, password))
```

:)